# How to force the PNUnit agent to run under .NET 4.0.

Tags: pnunit

I saw in the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/0wUEW1mD-S4
that Charlie answer a question with the next answer:

.NET 4.0 if necessary, using a separate process. PNUnit uses NUnit. 
but I think it calls NUnit at a lower level that bypasses the 
possibility of running in a separate process. To get around this, you 
might need to force the pnUnit agent to run under .NET 4.0. You can do 
that by setting an environment variable or by modifying the config 
file.

Charlie

So I want to know how to setting an enviroment variable for the agent?

Thanks,
Assaf.

Answer (score 1):

Edit pnunit-agent.exe.config and add the supportedRuntime directive like this:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

You can add this anywhere inside the configuration node.

Answer (score 0):

PNunit is from long time not maintained. I found a new open-source distributed runner that can run NUnit tests in distributed and in-parallel, you can check the projects [documentation](http://docs.meissarunner.com/). [Meissa Distrubuted Test Runner](https://meissarunner.com/)